# Getting error while deleting files from a folder using python script

Tags: python, opencsv

Im running a python script which deletes the files from a folder.im running the script in a virtual machine...but im getting error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\hyta\python_scripts\python_scr\file_delete.py", line 66, in <module
    compare_and_delete_sql_files(folder_a, folder_b, output_csv, sql_filenames)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\hyta\python_scripts\python_scr\file_delete.py", line 53, in compare_and_delete_sql_files
    os.remove(os.path.join(folder_b, filename))
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\Desktop\hyta\python_scripts\python_scr/folder_b\\scrum_1.sql'
```

My code:

```
import os
import csv

def extract_sql_filenames_from_yaml(yaml_file):
    sql_filenames = {}
    with open(yaml_file, 'r') as file:
        is_sql_section = False
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == 'sql:':
                is_sql_section = True
            elif is_sql_section and line.startswith('- name:') and not line.startswith('#'):
                filename = line.split(':')[-1].strip()
                if filename.endswith('.sql'):
                    sql_filenames[filename] = sql_filenames.get(filename, 0) + 1
            elif line.startswith('-') and not line.startswith('#'):
                is_sql_section = False
    return sql_filenames

def compare_and_delete_sql_files(folder_a, folder_b, output_csv, sql_filenames):
    processed_filenames = set()  # To keep track of processed filenames

    # Initialize CSV file writer
    with open(output_csv, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['SQL File Name', 'Occurrences', 'Match Status', 'Delete Status']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        # Iterate through each SQL filename extracted from YAML
        for filename, occurrences in sql_filenames.items():
            # Skip processing if the filename has already been processed
            if filename in processed_filenames:
                continue

            # Mark the filename as processed
            processed_filenames.add(filename)

            sql_file_a = os.path.join(folder_a, filename)
            match_status = 'Not Matched'
            delete_status = 'Not Deleted'

            # Check if the file exists in folder_a
            if os.path.exists(sql_file_a):
                # Compare with folder_b if necessary
                if os.path.exists(os.path.join(folder_b, filename)):
                    with open(sql_file_a, 'r') as f_a, open(os.path.join(folder_b, filename), 'r') as f_b:
                        lines_a = f_a.readlines()
                        lines_b = f_b.readlines()
                        if lines_a == lines_b:
                            match_status = 'Matched'
                            delete_status = 'Deleted'
                            # Delete file from folder_b
                            os.remove(os.path.join(folder_b, filename))

            # Write to CSV
            writer.writerow({'SQL File Name': filename, 'Occurrences': occurrences,
                             'Match Status': match_status, 'Delete Status': delete_status})

# Example usage
folder_a = '/path/to/folder/a'
folder_b = '/path/to/folder/b'
output_csv = 'comparison_results.csv'
yaml_file = 'example.yaml'

sql_filenames = extract_sql_filenames_from_yaml(yaml_file)
compare_and_delete_sql_files(folder_a, folder_b, output_csv, sql_filenames)
```

Comment: You're trying to delete a file while it is currently open within the python script. Maybe add deleted filenames to a list, and then delete them at the end, after all files are closed within the python script?

Comment: It's worth noting that what you're trying to do works on UNIX style OSes (e.g., Linux) because they allow you to unlink the name from a file that is open for I/O. Windows does not allow that. The file cannot be open by any process in order to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:

The error indicated that file is open, so it can't be deleted.

It is happening because you are deleting the file inside `with open` block of your code.

Execute this line `os.remove(os.path.join(folder_b, filename))` outside of the `open` block.

Make sure `folder_b` and `filename` variables are available outside of the `open` block.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you cannot delete a file if it is open in any other process hence [`[WinError 32]`.<sup>[microsoft.com]</sup>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-#ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION)

*Even if you did not open the file in your own `process`, it might have been opened in another `process` hence `os.remove()` is not guaranteed to succeed on windows.*

In your case, the `file` is `open` in your own process and you are attempting to delete the open file within the same [`context` <sup>[python.org]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#module-contextlib) hence the `[WinError 32]`.

Close the file and then delete immediately to ensure that you are guaranteed to still be the permitted file holder and you are not violating any sharing policy. <sup>[1]</sup>

Aside: This is another one of the many reasons why windows is *respectfully* such a *”great”* OS. Funny enough, there’s no such headache on Unix based OSes.

---

<sup><sub>[1] I’ve had one such experience where another process takes hold of the same file right before you want to use it again. This led to a mind blowing bug.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

Some initial Questions:

- Should the file path have a forward slash in it (see file path reference below)?
- Do you have the file opened via a different thread or process (going to assume you don't have it open on your PC)?
- Is the error on the first or last sql script that you are processing or was it able to process several sql scripts successfully but fail on that particular script file?

Let me know if you have additional info or logging built into the script operations.

File Path Reference:
C:\Users\Desktop\hyta\python_scripts\python_scr**/**folder_b\scrum_1.sql

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).